# How to make intersect of multiple Lists in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have search filter with multiple options where I want to filter results by multiple parameters (5 so far).
And what I want to do is to combine those filter options into single result list.

So I apply filter with distinct parameters and I got 5 different `lists`. What I want is intersection of those lists.

I found `intersect` function but it has just single parameter. I cant make it as intersection of multiple lists at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain multiples intersect like this.

```
fun main() {
    val a = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
    val b = listOf("b", "c", "d", "e")
    val c = listOf("c", "d", "e", "f")
    val d = listOf("d", "e", "f", "g")
   
    val result = a.intersect(b).intersect(c).intersect(d)
}
```

> Result: [d]

[See code snippet on play.kotlinlang.org](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)